# Simple Chat Application in php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a textArea in which the conversation from all users will be displayed.
When a user types a message and clicks send button, I want it to be displayed in textArea of all logged in users without use of database/file. I want it to be done using AJAX and PHP only.

```
            function send1()
            {
                req.open("GET", "process.php?q="+document.getElementById("msg").value, true);
                req.send();
            }
```

Comment: This is not how PHP works. Think of the security disaster it would be if clients could see private data that PHP intended to echo only to that client. You need a language better suited for chat applications. Look into [node.js](http://nodejs.org)

Comment: i am just doing it for learning purpose, i know about the security risks it involves. just wanted to know how can i achieve the thing i am trying

Comment: Also i dont want the backend to write and maintain Files,  I just want to know if there is a way to echo things to all clients

Comment: With PHP unless you're willing to work with a database, then no. Like I said before. PHP is not suited for chat applications. You need something event based. With Node.JS you *can* echo things to all clients. Chat applications in Node are usually less than 20 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be simpler to use WebSockets, but if you use AJAX, save your sent messages in the DB or a file and organize the client side to read this content every 30 seconds for example, also you should maintain in your db / file only the last 50 messages, if a new message is added, erase the first one. Try to understant how the server and the client side works, then think the model of your application, on paper.

Comment: yes the only way to do is by sockets. i just wanted to know if there was some way in php to do it.

Comment: There are WebSockets implementations in PHP, just surf the net

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use sockets to subscribe to a channel of messages. Ryan Bates has a great gem for Ruby on Rails that takes care of launching the channel server and the security issues that PhpMyCoder brought up.

Check out the [private-pub screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/316-private-pub) for a setup guide.

If you're not worried about storing anything in a database, you can use node.js. [Here's some sample node.js code](http://dhotson.tumblr.com/post/271733389/a-simple-chat-server-in-node-js)

Comment: I got it, so i guess there is no way to do it in php because of the security reasons

Comment: no, they are just addicted to RoR and Node.js :) you can use PHP too